# iOS: Is there a way to force a complete update of all an apps files, not just those that are different (delta)?

Tags: ios, store, updates, delta

According to this Q&A:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1779/_index.html

An app update is a package that is created by Apple and only contains files that have changed or are new. When a user updates their app, they only get the new files.

I've made a major update to an app, and I want a 'fresh start' with all files replaced.

Thanks for any ideas!

Chris

EDIT: I guess in the end, what I wanted to do was delete the app's own standard user defaults without having the the new version of the app do it as a matter of housekeeping. Now I know how updates actually work.

Comment: That Q&A is unclear about what happens with files that are or should be removed.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 possible situation:

1. You added a new file.
2. You deleted a file.
3. You changed a file.
4. You have a file that needs to be reset. (Like a SQLite file)

Don't worry about 1-3 apple will take care of those.

For case 4 however, you need to write some code to clear/reset those files first time it loads and then set a flag somewhere (User defaults may be) to make sure you are resetting the file every single load.

If you have any assets/files that won't match any of the above let me know.

Comment: That explains _why_ files are included in the package, but does not explain how to force the store to include all the bundle's files in the update package.

Comment: Why do you want to force the user to redone load images that are literally identical to the ones already downloaded?

Comment: @Tjalsma Store will include all bundle's files in the package, users who have the app will download the difference (and will delete anything that removed from the package) and new users will download them all. I agree with Aaron You need to explain what you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make a modification to every file. One that is significant, and more than just a metadata change. Or you could rename everything, thus the update would see everything as removed, and then an entirely new set added.

It's not clear *why* you want to do this though. There isn't any benefit to downloading a file that hasn't changed.